# JSF f:convertNumber works in a panel but does not work in a dialog

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-7, jsf-2.2

I have nearly the same code for 2 `<p:inputText>`s each wrapping a `<f:convertNumber/>` and a `<f:validateDoubleRange/>`. My `<p:inputText id="applesInner".../>` operates correctly with the min/max integer and fraction digits as well as rejecting letters (a-z).However, my `<p:inputText id="applesOutter"../>` seems to ignore `<f:convertNumber/>` completely. It accepts letters, and allows numbers with excessive fraction digits. I have tried eliminating all other fields in my dialog and insert a `<h:form>` to enclose the `<p:outputPanel id="dlgContent"/>` but it did not work. Validations trigger correctly for letters, input like 2erf, and 224356 so I know such input will not be allowed into the DB. Anyone have an idea on `<f:convertNumber>` used successfully in a dialog? I am using **(JSF2.2, JDK7, Java EE6 Web, and PrimesFaces 5.3)**
 Code is below:

Thank You

```
    <!-- code here that does a <ui:include/> of the code below -->

**my-training.xhtml**
<p:dialog id="exampleFileDlg" 
    header="This is for JSF"
    widgetVar="appleUploadFileDialog"
    >

    <p:outputPanel id="dlgContent"
        <iframe..../>
        <p:panel: id="reviewInfoPanel">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel for="applesInner"  value="# of apples:"/>
                 <h:panelGroup>
                     <p:inputText id="applesInner" 
                                  value="#{fruitman.cart.numApples}"
                                  type="number"
                                  required="true" 
                                  placeholder="Apples between 0.1 and 99.9"
                                  requiredMessage="# Apples is required" 
                                  validatorMessage="Please enter a number between 0.1 and 99.9" 
                                  converterMessage="Apple # is not valid. Please enter a number between 0.1 and 99.9">
                         <f:convertNumber maxIntegerDigits="2"   
                                          minIntegerDigits="1"
                                          minFractionDigits="0"
                                          maxFractionDigits="1"
                                          groupingUsed="true"/>
                         <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0.1" maximum="99.9"/>
                         <p:ajax event="blur" update="msgApplesInner"/>
                     </p:inputText>                        
                     <p:message id="msgApplesInner" for="applesInner"/>
                </h:panelGroup>        
            <h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>   
    <p/:outputPanel>
</p:dialog> 


    <p:confirmDialog widgetVar="approveNumberOfApples" 
                     header="Approving Apples" message="Are you sure you want to approve this number of apples?" closable="false">
        <center>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="courseHeader" >
                <p:commandButton 
                    value="Yes" 
                    id="yesApproveApples"
                    actionListener="#{fruitman.cart.approveApples}"
                    onstart="PF('saveDlg').show();" 
                    oncomplete="PF('saveDlg').hide(); 
                                PF('appleUploadFileDialog').hide();"                                               
                    onclick="PF('approveNumberOfApples').hide();"/>

                <p:commandButton value="No"
                                 id="noApproveApples" 
                                 process="@this"                                          
                               onclick="PF('approveNumberOfApples').hide();"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </center>
    </p:confirmDialog>


<p:panel id="fruitWorksPanel">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputLabel for="applesOutter"  
                       value="# of CEUs:" style="font-weight:bold"/>
        <h:panelGroup>
            <p:inputText id="applesOutter" 
                         value="#{fruitman.cart.customer.numApples}"
                         type="number"
                         required="true" 
                         placeholder="Apples between 0.1 and 99.9"
                         requiredMessage="# Apples is required" 
                         validatorMessage="Please enter a number between 0.1 
                                           and 99.9" 
                         converterMessage="Apple # is not valid. Please enter
                                            a number between 0.1 and 99.9">
                         <f:convertNumber maxIntegerDigits="2"
                                          minIntegerDigits="1"
                                          maxFractionDigits="1"
                                          groupingUsed="true"/>
                         <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0.1" 
                                                maximum="99.9"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:message id="msgApplesOuter" 
                       for="applesOutter"/>
        </h:panelGroup>

        <h:panelGroup layout="inline-block"/>
        <h:panelGroup layout="inline-block">
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" 
                             id="submitCEUBtn"
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <br/>                                      
   </h:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: You have a LOT going on here.   Why not try and keep shrinking your sample down until you can narrow it down.  I feel like with so much going on in this dialog(s) you might actually be causing the issue.  If you can narrow it down to the simplest reproducible example we can try and diagnose it.

Comment: Hey Melloware, I removed unnecessary styling and the process and update attributes of my command button which I confirmed did NOT change the operation of the convertNumber for <p:inputText id="applesInner" />.

Comment: You still have an `iframe` there.. Don't know what could be messing it up. For this case you'd better implement a new dialog from scratch, with minimal requirements for `f:convertNumber`. If you get it working, then keep adding things until you get the state of the original component and see at what point it does fail.

Comment: UPDATE. My data type was BigDecimal when it should have been Double. The actual code(used in 3 different places) all worked except for one in a dialog. Changing the datatype to Double fixed the last code block.